# Which BBQ grill is better: cast iron or steel

Tags: grilling, barbecue

I am going to buy a BBQ and I am torn between a cast iron BBQ and a stainless steel BBQ. What are the advantages and downsides of each?

Comment: Are you specifically asking about cast iron grates vs. stainless steel grates?

Comment: What kind of grilling/BBQing are you interesting in doing? Searing steaks and/or smoking ribs for 4-hours?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you are talking about different types of grill grates:

[Choosing Grill Grates](http://barbecuetricks.com/grate-better-best-choosing-grill-grates/)

In general, cast-iron gives you better heat retention (flip-side: slower preheating) and better non-stick behavior if well seasoned. However maintenance with cast-iron can be a bit of a hassle. You have to develop and maintain seasoning and also take precautions against rust.

Stainless steel does not rust and is easier to maintain, however it is less non-stick and won't give you the same grill marks that you get with cast-iron.

Ceramic coated cast-iron is supposed to be a good compromise, however, I really hated the ones I had as they were very hard to clean and the coating eventually cracked, rusted AND chipped off.

**tl;dr - If you are willing to put in the maintenance, cast-iron is generally the superior choice. If you aren't, go for high quality stainless steel grates (like [these](http://merc-images.s3.amazonaws.com/1339/Weber-Stainless-Steel-Cooking-Grates-for-Spirit-and-Genesis-Series-Grill-Accessory/Weber-Stainless-Steel-Cooking-Grates-for-Spirit-and-Genesis-Series-Grill-Accessory_0_0.jpg)) -- you won't be missing all that much.**

Answer (score 1):

See also the answer to a similar question I had regarding a choice between porcelain and stainless steel:

[Stainless vs Enameled Porcelain Grates?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/23708/stainless-vs-enameled-porcelain-grates)

(I went with stainless and have been happy with the performance)